# Is there a "standard" way to validate xpointers?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpointer

I'm looking to validate the xpointers (shorthand) in one xml document, that means that all ids in the referenced document are present.
By standard I mean something already built-in in the XSL transformation engines.

example:

document 1:

```
<source xpointer="doc2.xml#ID_1" />
```

document 2:

```
<object xmlID="ID_1"/>
```

So far I've seen that there's not much support in that respect from the xslt engines, and most of the implementation has to be done in the stylesheets itself.

Regards
Vlax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT does not directly support validation of XPointers, but you may find Lea Hayes' [**XPointer Framework for XSLT 2.0**](http://rotorz.com/xml/2009/XPointer/) to be helpful.